# Crash report not uploaded or received by Firebase server using Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Im trying to add flutter crashlytics to my app and have followed the official documentation and setup guides.

in my project level `build.gradle` Ive added:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
```

and in my app level `build.gradle` Ive added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
}
```

Then in my `main()` Ive added the below:

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

void main() async{
  //below will ensure initializations happen before calling runApp()
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // this is needed for all firebase stuff from August 27, initialize at top
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Admob.initialize();
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  // Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And to force the crash to test, I used the below line in a `onPressed` function on another screen in my app.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

This is the log on crash:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(19056): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(19056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19056): Process: com.my_company.my_app, PID: 19056
E/AndroidRuntime(19056): io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlyticsTestCrash: This is a test crash caused by calling .crash() in Dart.
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.lambda$crash$1(FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin$H0t0BleSpjDMVvqpx8Hy-ZKGwP8.run(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(19056):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process (19056): Sending signal. PID: 19056 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Which looks like it is crashing as expected but at the firebase website I am stuck at the following:

[image]

I know that the app has to restart to send the report and I have restarted my app many times after crash, but still nothing is received by firebase,

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to wait for some time, around 24hrs before it reflects, especially if it's the first time.

Comment: oh wow, like that would have been helpful to mention in the documentation, would save a  lot of headache..

Comment: Thanks Joseph, you were right, the system updated after about 24 hours and has the test crashes logged.

Comment: Good to hear that. You are welcome.